# Assertion failed while exporting depth images from h5 file

Tags: python, opencv, hdf5, h5py

Th h5 file does not have a group or subgroup, and when I try to extract images it shows me this error. These are depth images.

This code works for h5 file with group i.e. images then I just write `image_ds = hf['images']` and it works, but for h5 file without group doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Maybe some error in imwrite function, because when I `print(IMAGE_arr)` and `print(imagename)` it prints fine. The number of dimensions are 3 and type is float32
Here is my code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import cv2

save_dir = 'C:/Users.../depth_imgs'

with h5py.File('depth.h5', 'r') as hf:
    image_ds = hf
    for imagename in image_ds.keys():
        IMAGE_arr = image_ds[imagename][()]
        cv2.imwrite(f"{save_dir}/{imagename}", IMAGE_arr)
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Loaded data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw1K1.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPWIr.png)

Comment: The error is related to the image data, and not the procedure. You may need to adjust cv2 parameters. Which `imagename` creates the error message?

Comment: `print(IMAGE_arr.dtype, IMAGE_arr.shape)`

Comment: .....
float32 (2, 600, 400)
float32 (2, 600, 400)
float32 (2, 600, 450)
float32 (2, 600, 409)
float32 (2, 600, 449)
float32 (2, 600, 450)
float32 (2, 600, 400)
float32 (2, 600, 493)
float32 (2, 600, 284)
float32 (2, 600, 450)
float32 (2, 600, 338)
.....

Comment: @kcw78 I don't understand, what do you mean by which imagename?

Comment: `imagename` in your loop...to figure out which dataset is causing the error. Or do you get it for every dataset (key)? I didn't expect to see those array shapes `(2,600,400)`. I expected (width, height, 3) or something similar (depending on number of channels). And you have floats, not unsigned ints. Do you know how the data was loaded to this file?

Comment: shapes are wrong. opencv's imwrite expects `(height, width, channels)`. floats aren't a problem in themselves, but imwrite will assume a value range of 0.0 to 1.0 for floats. for uint8, the value range is 0 to 255

Comment: @kcw78 I think for every dataset (key). I edit the post and there I put 2 pictures where it can be seen how data is loaded.

Comment: '2' here refers to two different depth estimates by two different neural networks --- one trained on mostly indoor images, and the other on outdoor images.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70894121/how-to-extract-images-with-2-different-depth-estimation-from-h5-file-in-a-folder